# Error in Javascript Code

Tags: javascript, html

```
   if(e.target.id == "cited"){
        alert(e.target.innerHTML);
        if (document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML == "[1]") {
            display = "sometext1";  
        }
        else if (document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML == "[2]") {
            display = "sometext2";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML == "[3]") {
            display = "sometext3";
        }
```

Alright, well when I hover over my [3] it displays "sometext2" when it should be displaying "sometext3". [2] and [3] is on the same page.
I did add a quick debug in to see if it picking up the wrong innerHTML by doing:

```
alert(e.target.innerHTML);
```

it displays the right one when I hover over in the alert message, but I don't know why it is displaying the wrong toolTip. Any help here?

```
    document.onmousemove = function(e)
{
    // e.target, e.srcElement and e.toElement contains the element clicked.
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var display;
    if(e.target.id == "cited"){
    //  alert(e.target.innerHTML);
        if (document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML == "[1]") {
            display = "sometext1";  
        }
        else if (document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML == "[2]") {
            display = "sometext2";
        }
        else if (document.getElementById(e.target.id).innerHTML == "[3]") {
            display = "sometext3";
        }
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.top = y-50+"px";
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.left = x+"px";
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("toolTip").innerHTML = "<p>"+display+"</p>";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.visibility = "hidden"; 
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you may have more than one element with the id `cited`. Each id should be unique per html page.

Comment: Why don't you just use `e.target`?

Comment: @Blender Cause I want to get the value of the innerHTML to tell what to display. I know a little bad way, but I am just doing it quick.

Comment: @Andbdrew I got two of them with the same id, I figured this wouldn't be an issue cause I am comparing the contents of the id's which is why I got them on the same id. I don't want to make different id for each one to do the same exact thing.

Comment: @Matt that is a problem :) ID's must be unique on a page or things will break.

Comment: Id must be unique. Besides that can you please post where are you assigning the var display?

Comment: @ricardohdz give me one minute.

Comment: Try changing the event from document.onmousemove to document.onmouseover. Also, is always better to use strict equals ===

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bad way of fixing it:

```
document.onmousemove = function (e) {
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;
    var display;

    if (e.target.id == "cited") {
        if (e.target.innerHTML == "[1]") {
            display = "sometext1";
        } else if (e.target.innerHTML == "[2]") {
            display = "sometext2";
        } else if (e.target.innerHTML == "[3]") {
            display = "sometext3";
        }

        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.top = y - 50 + "px";
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.left = x + "px";
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.visibility = "visible";
        document.getElementById("toolTip").innerHTML = "<p>" + display + "</p>";
    } else {
        document.getElementById("toolTip").style.visibility = "hidden";
    }
}
```

A better way would be to add event listeners to all of the elements and change their `id`s to `class`es, but that gets clumsy, so here's a jQuery solution:

```
$('.cited').mousemove(function(e) {
    $('#tooltip').css({
        top: e.pageY - 50 + 'px',
        left: e.pageX + 'px',
        text: $(this).data('tooltip')
    });
}).mouseleave(function() {
    $('#tooltip').hide();
}).mouseenter(function() {
    $('#tooltip').show();
});
```

You'd change the HTML to this:

```
<span class="cited" data-tooltip="This is the tooltip text">Foo</span>
<span class="cited" data-tooltip="This is the tooltip text">Bar</span>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is now fixed. I know what I did wrong and I often don't catch it till I do this.

Answer (score 2):

One problem seems to be that you have multiple elements on the same page with the same id. From your code, it seems that you have at least three elements with id `cited`.

If you want to refer to more than one element, you should use classes.

Comment: So what different would that make in the code? Wouldn't I get the same exact thing happening if I use classes or id.

Comment: Oooh... I just reread exactly how I did it... Now I see why it is causing the thing... Durrr.... Dumbass moment by me.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is now fixed. I turn those into classes and then gave each one an id of citedx where x changes.

Comment: Yeah thanks... I still can't believe I didn't catch that sooner. It made sense after I reread that and what you told me, I looked closer. I felt dumb after that... and I make that mistake a lot of times.